# php code for displaying Featured Article in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am new in using joomla.

I want to display Featured Articles on my site but I've searched on different tutorials but none of them has a code-wise instruction on how to display the featured articles.

and is displaying articles by category any different from displaying featured articles?

thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a menu for your site, you have to choose the menu type like: [image: menu types]